# How to install a package with pip from git if it has multiple subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am working with a repo which has the following structure:

- foo/bar/setup.py
- foo/bar/mypackage

I am attempting to install this package using something like:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo-namegit@commithash#egg=mypackage&subdirectory=foo/bar
```

However, it just hangs here and doesn't seem to respond.

Their [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) doesn't have an example of a multiple nested directory package path like that. However it does say, emphasis mine:

> For projects where setup.py is not in the root of project, "subdirectory" component is used. **Value of "subdirectory" component should be a path starting from root of the project to where setup.py is located**

What does the properly formed installation from pip for a multiple-directory look like?

The above is returning errors such as:

```
  Could not find a tag or branch 'commit', assuming commit.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/wf/89r2567s5hv48lj1g9l65mbw0000gp/T/pip-gAwA3W-build/setup.py'
```

I see this using all versions of pip I tested (9.0.1 and 8.1.1).

Here is the detailed log:

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git@hash#egg=projectname&subdirectory=lib/python
[1] 4195

Collecting projectname from git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repogit@hash#egg=projectname
  Cloning ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git (to 8d109c760ae8a9599299924be1b78645e2617a50) to /private/var/folders/wf/89r2567s5hv48lj1g9l65mbw0000gp/T/pip-build-w01D4G/repo
  Could not find a tag or branch 'hash', assuming commit.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/wf/89r2567s5hv48lj1g9l65mbw0000gp/T/pip-build-w01D4G/repo/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wf/89r2567s5hv48lj1g9l65mbw0000gp/T/pip-build-w01D4G/repo/

[1]+  Exit 1                  pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git@hash#egg=projectname
```

It looks like after the initial `subdirectory` line where I call it, that part of the pip command is disappearing?

Comment: Just noting that there's no @ before egg (as in it should be `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo-namegit@commithash#egg=mypackage&subdirectory=foo/bar` instead of `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo-namegit@commithash#@egg=mypackage&subdirectory=foo/bar)`

Comment: `subdirectory` is definitely how to specify a subdirectory (i.e. `pip install 'git+https://github.com/pallets/click.git@master#egg=click-example-naval&subdirectory=examples/naval/'`). I think your problem is caused by something else (problems cloning the repo? incorrect syntax specifying the commit sha? ...).

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca I removed that and added additional logs, it's still not doing what the docs seem to suggest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using multiple operators with pip, the entire argument needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo-name.git@commithash#"egg=mypackage&subdirectory=foo/bar"
```

Otherwise, pip drops anything after the & and does not successfully recognize this.

Comment: Quick notes: 1) it's your shell doing the `drop anything after the &`, not pip & 2) you can enclose in quotes (double or single) the entire argument to pip install (i.e. `pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/owner/repo-namegit@commithash#egg=mypackage&subdirectory=foo/bar"`).